# About synchronization for windows phone application

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I insert data into sqlite database in windows phone application project from data in sql database in server using wcf service at the application start loading?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do such a lengthy operation at the application start, since you have limited amount of time (15 seconds if I remember correctly) or else WP7 platform closes your application.

Upon load you can query your web service, cast the data into necessary format (like classes) and insert the data using your dbContext. Then just call submitChanges on your context. For more info on dbContext, check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) article.

Your wcf service should be able to query sql server and return the data.